# Disable user profile editing for one user

Tags: users, profiles

I have being looking in internet how can I disable the option of edit profile in Wordpress for a user and I didn't find a good way. The problem is that I want that the 95% of users can edit their profiles (address, telephone,...) but there is another 5% that I don't want them to have access to the profile section. The best solution for me is to select manually the users that I want to disable but I also thought about create a role or a group of users to manage it.

There is no plugin for this and the only thing I have found is the following code but it is not working.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'user_profile_fields_disable');

function user_profile_fields_disable() {

    global $pagenow;

    // apply only to user profile or user edit pages
    if ($pagenow!=='profile.php' && $pagenow!=='user-edit.php') {
        return;
    }

    // do not change anything for the administrator
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    return;
    }
    if (current_user_can('custom_role') {
      add_action( 'admin_footer', 'user_profile_fields_disable_js' );
    }      
}
/**
 * Disables selected fields in WP Admin user profile (profile.php, user-edit.php)
 */
function user_profile_fields_disable_js() {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            var fields_to_disable = ['email', 'role'];
            for(i=0; i<fields_to_disable.length; i++) {
                if ( $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).length ) {
                    $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

You have to substitute the "custom_role" with the name of the role I have assign to the user. Is that code obsolete or bad? Any idea of how to solve it?

---

Thank you very much G.M.! It was a great and perfect solution.
I forgot to tell that I am using the Woocommerce plugin and I still have the problem of profile editing in the "my account" page.

Could you add something to the plugin above to remove the "edit" link? I don't mind that the user can read his profile but don't allow to edit it.

Here is what I am talking about (some fields are in spanish):
[image]

Thanks again for your work!

Comment: Why not just revoke admin-area access to `custom_role` users? Don't give them the `read` capability in other words. Then provide them with an area on the front end where they can edit their account. [plugins exist](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/Front-End-Accounts) to do a lot of that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to completerly remove the possibility for an user to access on profile, you can

1. Give admin possibility to choose which user can access on profile and which not
2. Remove the profile link from menu and from admin bar
3. Ensure the profile is not accessible even if accessed directly by manually typing address

### Step 1

First point is pretty easy using ['personal_options'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options), ['edit_user_profile_update'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update) hooks:

```
add_action( 'personal_options', 'rpa_profile_ban_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'rpa_profile_ban_field_save' );

function rpa_profile_ban_field( \WP_User $user ) {
  $current = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( ! is_admin() || $user->ID === $current->ID ) return;
  if ( ! user_can( $current, 'edit_users' ) ) return;
  $target = new WP_User( $user->ID ); 
  if ( $target->exists() &&  ! user_can( $target, 'edit_users' ) ) {
    $banned = (int) get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_profile_banned', TRUE );
  ?>
  <table class="form-table"><tbody><tr>
  <th scope="row">Profile Ban</th><td>
  <input<?php checked(1, $banned); ?> name="_profile_banned" value="1" type="checkbox">
  Ban user to enter profile?
  </td></tr></tbody></table>
  <?php
  }
}

function rpa_profile_ban_field_save( $userid ) {
  $current = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( ! is_admin() || $user->ID === $current->ID ) return;
  if ( ! user_can( $current, 'edit_users' ) ) return;
  $target = new WP_User( $userid );
  if ( ! $target->exists() || user_can( $target, 'edit_users' ) ) return; 
  $ban = filter_input( INPUT_POST, '_profile_banned', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
  if ( (int) $ban > 0 ) {
    update_user_meta( $userid, '_profile_banned', 1 );
  } elseif ( get_user_meta( $userid, '_profile_banned', TRUE ) ) {
    delete_user_meta( $userid, '_profile_banned' );
  }
}
```

Using this code administrators can go to each user and disable the access to profile page.
This is the output of the code:

[image: Ban user fields]

### Step 2

Remove profile link from menu is easy using [`remove_menu_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rpa_profile_menu_remove' );

function rpa_profile_menu_remove(){
  $remove = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_profile_banned', TRUE );
  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) && (int) $remove > 0 ) {
    remove_menu_page( 'profile.php' );
  } 
}
```

Remove profile link from admin bar is a little more complex, or better, *completely remove* the user menu on top right is easy using `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account')` (see [`WP_Admin_Bar` docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar)), but it is "unaesthetic" and also you remove the possibility to logout.
So a better solution is remove just the link to profile:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'rpa_profile_adminbar_remove' );

function rpa_profile_adminbar_remove() {
  $remove = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_profile_banned', TRUE );
  if ( (int) $remove !== 1 || current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) return;
  global $wp_admin_bar;
  $account = (array) $wp_admin_bar->get_node('my-account');
  $info = (array) $wp_admin_bar->get_node('user-info');
  $logout = (array) $wp_admin_bar->get_node('logout');
  $account['href'] = $info['href'] = '#';
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('my-account');
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('user-info');
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('edit-profile');
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('logout');
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node($account);
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node($info);
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node($logout);
}
```

### Step 3

Using all the code above, an user do not see a link to profile anymore, however, just typing `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/profile.php` and profile page is shown.
This can be easily solved:

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'rpa_profile_banned_check' );
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'rpa_profile_banned_msg' );
add_action( 'all_admin_notices', 'rpa_profile_banned_msg' );

function rpa_profile_banned_check() {
  $remove = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_profile_banned', TRUE );
  if ( (int) $remove === 1 && ! current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'pbanned' => 1), admin_url('index.php') ) );
    exit();
  }
}

function rpa_profile_banned_msg() {
  if ( current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) return;
  static $show = false;
  if ( current_filter() === 'load-index.php' ) {
    $msg = (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pbanned', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $banned = (int) get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_profile_banned', TRUE );
    $show = ( $msg === $banned && $banned === 1 );    
  } elseif ( current_filter() === 'all_admin_notices' && $show ) {
    echo '<div class="error"><p>Sorry, you are not allowed to edit your profile.</p></div>';
  }
}
```

The previous code check if the user is banned when the profile page is loaded, and if so redirect the user to dashboard adding a variable in the url that allow to show a message that inform user that he/she is not allowed to see profile.

This is how the message appear:

[image: Admin notices for user not allowed to see profile]

---

All code, as a plugin, available in a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/gmazzap/11070063).

Comment: Brilliant answer once again G.M. +1

Comment: @gmazzap -  Nice info - even from the 'last decade'. Note that the GIST is not available as of this date. But the code appears to work OK.

Comment: @RickHellewell the Gist is here https://gist.github.com/gmazzap/11070063 but I've no idea if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody helped me to get the same for Woocommerce 2.0.XX. The first thing is to install the G.M. plugin above. Then, I have edited the file /plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-address.php and you have to add in line 28:

```
$checkProfile =  get_user_meta( $customer_id, '_profile_banned', TRUE );
```

And also you have to substitude in line 45:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg('address', $name, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id( 'edit_address' ) ) ) ); ?>" class="edit"><?php _e( 'Edit', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
```

with:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($checkProfile) && $checkProfile==1) {
echo '';
} else {
echo '<a href="', esc_url( add_query_arg('address', $name, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id( 'edit_address' ) ) ) ), '" class="edit">', _e( 'Edit', 'woocommerce' ), '</a>';
}
?>
```